# IOS10.3 localnotification objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, localnotification

I wanted to create a local Notification in IOS 10.3 using objective -c for a certain date of date picker, but it is not working for some reason.
here is my code

```
-(IBAction)addReminder:(id)sender
{
    NSDate *date =self.datePicker.date;

    UNMutableNotificationContent *content = [[UNMutableNotificationContent alloc]init];
    content.title = [NSString localizedUserNotificationStringForKey:@"wake up" arguments:nil];
    content.body = [NSString localizedUserNotificationStringForKey:@"it is time" arguments:nil];

    NSDateComponents *dateComponent = [[NSDateComponents alloc]init];
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *Components = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute fromDate:date];
    dateComponent.hour = [Components hour];
    dateComponent.minute = [Components minute];


    UNCalendarNotificationTrigger *trigger = [UNCalendarNotificationTrigger triggerWithDateMatchingComponents:dateComponent repeats:NO];

    UNNotificationRequest *request = [UNNotificationRequest requestWithIdentifier:@"Alarm" content:content trigger:trigger];
    UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
    // Ask user for the permission
    [center requestAuthorizationWithOptions:(UNAuthorizationOptionAlert + UNAuthorizationOptionSound)
                          completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                              if (granted)
                              {
                                  // Add your notification to center
                                  [center addNotificationRequest:request
                                           withCompletionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
                                               if (error != nil)
                                               {
                                                   NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
                                               }
                                               NSLog(@"finished scheduling");
                                           }];
                              }
                              else
                              {
                                  NSLog(@"%i",granted);
                              }
                          }];
}
```

After I run my code and I choose a certain date. The notification does not work and I get 0 for "granted variable" in the console.

Comment: Did you grant the permission the first time you got asked? What happens if you go to your app in system Settings app, are notifications enabled there?

Comment: I am actually testing it on simulator. Do I need to grant it permission before I run it on simulator. Thanks

Comment: Yes, you always need to grant permission.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Just a quick question if you don't mind. Where shall I grant that permission. Is it in the AppDelegate file ?

Comment: That's the usual place, but it doesn't matter - the way you do it should be fine. Important part is to press "Allow" when the system presents the alert. This will happen only once per installation, when you first request authorization. After this you can change this in Settings app, or remove your app from device/simulator and install it again.